# Multiple settings for multiple parts of a text in the same TextView Android java

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling with the idea of adding different (font sizes, and alignments) for different parts of a **String** in the same **TextView**.

What I want exactly could be shown in the picture below where I want the first line in the TextView to be centered and with a size that could be set programmatically.

Also, from the second line, I want the text to be left-aligned and set to a limit of 12 characters per line.

So, how to do this?

[image]

This is the XML code for the TextView and it is being added inside a **LinearLayout tag** :

```
<TextView
          android:id="@+id/tray1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight=".70"
          android:background="#B38888"
          android:text="トレイ1"
          android:textAlignment="viewStart"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: So is there any specific requirement of using a Single TextView ?

Comment: @Swayangjit
Actually, I know that it could be done with two separate TextViews but it is clickable and there is some action upon that. if I do it with two I would have redundancy with the code.  Eventually, I will end up with 4 TexViews...

Comment: How about make a custom view? Say `ArticleView` (I saw your requirement is pretty similar to display an article, a centered title and the content). And this custom view could derives from any ViewGroup, say `RelativeLayout`, you will be able to put anything you want into the custom view, and layout as per your spec (12 chars per line etc). And for sure you can add your own attribute to accept the params like `title` / `content` / `charsNumberPerLineLimit` etc.

Comment: And you can make the whole custom view clickable, to eliminate the code redundant.

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. looks interesting! but do you have a ref on how to implement sth similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that using the power of [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder)

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("PUT YOUR STRING HERE");
// set part of the str to bold
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), fromIndex, toIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// set part of the str to bigger size
str.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), fromIndex, toIndex, 0);

// set alignment of it to center
str.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), fromIndex, toIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

activeTray.setText(str);
```

NOTE: you need to specify the integers **fromIndex** & **toIndex** where they represent the indexes of the character inside the **PUT YOUR STRING HERE**